Creating Issue with Github HTTP Rest API throws unprocessable entity even though payload is copied as is from the documentation
I am trying to run this:
curl --location 'https://api.github.com/repos/abc/example/issues' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <AUTH_TOKEN>' \
--header 'X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "title": "Found a bug",
  "body": "I'\''m having a problem with this.",
  "milestone": 1,
  "labels": [
    "bug"
  ]
}'

But this is returning 422:Unprocessable entity:
{
    "message": "Validation Failed",
    "errors": [
        {
            "value": 1,
            "resource": "Issue",
            "field": "milestone",
            "code": "invalid"
        }
    ],
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/issues/issues#create-an-issue"
}

As far as I see in documentation it needs to have a number, null or string but keeping 1 doesn't work. I wanted to know what am i supposed to put in milestone? Does it have to be associated with some value?

Judging from the error message, the milestone number (1) you are referring to in the request does not seem to exist. Please read about milestones first and create one then retry your request or do not associate the issue with any milestone by removing the milestone field from the request JSON payload (milestone field is optional according to the REST API documentation):

milestone - null or string or integer
The number of the milestone to associate this issue with. NOTE: Only users with push access can set the milestone for new issues.

